# Why can't iodide be oxidised to iodate in acidic medium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, oxidation-state, reduction-potential

Even if we use a strong oxidising agent like 'permanganate ion in acidic medium' it doesn't help oxidise iodide to iodate, but a relatively weaker oxidising agent 'permanganate ion in alkaline medium' helps to form iodate from iodide.

[I have found one discussion similar to this but it's not convincing.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67636/why-does-kmno4-oxidize-iodide-to-iodine-in-acidic-medium-whereas-iodide-to-ioda?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Even in alkaline medium the potential is negative although significantly lesser than in acidic medium.
Then how does the reaction even proceed in alkaline but not in acidic?

Comment: Draw yourself a chart of standard redox potentials for eventually involved redox systems as functions of pH, involving formally and implicitly [H+] or [OH-] to the redox potentials pH dependent values. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_%28data_page%29

Comment: Note that there can be kinetic reasons, as $\ce{IO-}$ is more stable in alkaline solutins than $\ce{HIO}$ in acidic one.

Answer (score 5):

Permanganate oxidizes iodide to iodine $\ce{I2}$ at all pH values. In acidic conditions, the reaction is finished here. But in basic solution, the iodine $\ce{I2}$ is transformed into iodide and iodate according to $$\ce{3I2 + 6 OH^- -> 5 I- + IO3^- + 3 H2O}$$The mixture  iodide + iodate reacts the other way as soon as the solution becomes acidic : $$\ce{5I^- + IO3^- + 6 H+ -> 3 I2 + 3 H2O}$$

Comment: So its because of the property of iodine & not permanganate that we see a larger difference of oxidation state in the reactions in the basic pH mediums?