# What products are formed when KMnO4 and KI react with each other in "weakly basic" medium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, redox, stoichiometry

While solving JEE Advanced 2020 (Paper 2) questions, I came across this particular question:

> [image]

According to the final answer key, its answer is **6**.

In my chemistry book (NCERT Chemistry), the following equation is given:

In neutral or faintly alkaline solutions:
$\ce{2MnO4- + H2O + I- -> 2MnO2 + 2OH- + IO3- ~~~~(1)}$

If I go by this equation, the answer should have been **0**.

According to the same book,
In basic medium:  $\ce{MnO4- + I- -> MnO2 + I2 ~~~~~(2)}$

This gives the correct answer.

Is there a difference between "weakly basic" and "faintly alkaline"? What I can conclude from here is that the reaction in weakly basic medium is equivalent to that in basic medium, and not in faintly alkaline medium.

Could anyone please explain why the answer is **6** and confirm which equation is valid for the given case?

---

Side question:

I had learned that in basic medium, n-factor of $\ce{KMnO4}$ is **1** due to the following reaction:

$$\ce{MnO4- -> MnO4^2-}$$
This transition is not seen in the reaction (2). Could someone explain this?

---

**UPDATE:
After doing some analysis, I have been able to conclude the following:

1. Acidic medium:
   $\ce{MnO4^- + I^- -> Mn^2+ + I2}$
2. Neutral / Faintly Alkaline medium:
   $\ce{MnO4^- + I^- -> MnO2 + IO3^-}$
3. Basic (not alkaline - so that I2 is not oxidised to $\ce{IO3^-}$ due to presence of $\ce{OH^-}$ ions) / Weakly Basic medium:
   $\ce{MnO4^- + I^- -> MnO2 + I2}$
4. Alkaline medium / Strongly Alkaline medium:
   $\ce{MnO4^- + I^- -> MnO4^2- + IO3^-}$

Could anyone please confirm if the above equations are correct?**

Comment: See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67636/why-does-kmno4-oxidize-iodide-to-iodine-in-acidic-medium-whereas-iodide-to-ioda

Comment: With increasing pH, preference of MnO2 kicks in before I2 disproportionation of I2 to I- and IO3-.

Comment: @Poutnik so does that mean that even in the alkaline medium, MnO2 will be formed instead of MnO4(2-)

Comment: MnO4^2- is preferred in strongly alkaline medium. If not alkaline enough, it disproportionates to MnO2 and MnO4-.

Comment: Ok, thank you for adding that, so in the case of weakly basic medium, MnO4^(2-) did form but it got dissociated into MnO2 and MnO4(-) Hence, the ‘MnO2’ in the equation 3 (in the update section).

Comment: I still have some doubts. Coming to the equations 2 and 3 (in the update section), I had deduced solely from the answer key of the question that faintly alkaline and weakly basic mediums have a difference, but do they really differ? If yes, then in what ways?

Comment: Rather in mild alkalic solution, MnO4^2- does not form at all, unless as a not detectable intermediate product. // Those 2 ways of wording is hard to quantify.

Comment: Oh alright; So are all the four chemical equations correct? // Yeah, even I think that, thank you for confirming // I have considered that in basic (but not alkaline) and alkaline medium, different reactions occur due to the fact that in alkaline medium, OH^- ions are released. Could you please confirm if I am correct here