Oxidation of Iodide ion by potassium permanganate
Why does KMnO4 oxidize iodide ions in acidic condition into I2, but in basic condition into IO3-

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150511/what-products-are-formed-when-kmno4-and-ki-react-with-each-other-in-weakly-basi
